# I have nested json data and i want to find name value from below json and in result only return name and route. #node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is my JSON, from this json I want to access name and route:

```
"medicineDetail" : {
        "products" : [ 
            {
                "hits" : [ 
                    {
                        "field" : "name",
                        "value" : "<em>Humira</em>"
                    }
                ],
                "name" : "Humira",
                "prescribable_name" : "Adalimumab 40 mg Injectable Solution [Humira]",
                "country" : "EU",
                "ndc_product_codes" : null,
                "dpd_codes" : null,
                "ema_product_codes" : [ 
                    "EMEA/H/C/000481"
                ],
                "dosage_form" : "Injection, solution",
                "strength" : {
                    "number" : "40",
                    "unit" : "mg"
                },
                "route" : "Subcutaneous",
                "approved" : true,
                "unapproved" : false,
                "generic" : false,
                "otc" : false,
                "mixture" : false,
                "allergen" : false,
                "vaccine" : false,
                "ingredients" : [ 
                    {
                        "drugbank_id" : "DB00051",
                        "name" : "Adalimumab",
                        "cas" : "331731-18-1",
                        "strength" : {
                            "number" : "40",
                            "unit" : "mg"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "images" : []
            }, 
    ]
```

Expected result:

```
{"name" : "Humira", "route": "Oral"}
```

I tried this:

```
let medicine = await medicineModel.findOne({
  "medicineDetail.products": { $elemMatch: { route: req.params.name } }
});
```

Comment: Can you add the expected result?

Comment: @SuleymanSah {"name" : "Humira", "route": "Oral"}

Comment: padam please don't forget to check my answer, and give feedback whether it worked or not.

Comment: yes Its working sorry for late response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query without needing elemMatch.

```
let medicine = await medicineModel
  .findOne({ "medicineDetail.products.route": req.params.name })
  .select("name route");
```

You can find more info about select here:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#executing